# Erro: expected class-name before

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto onde eu tenho uma classe online que herda de uma classe X, onde essa classe X precisa dar um `new` em um objeto da classe online. Quando eu faço isso acontece o erro, devido à herança eu acredito:

> expected class-name before

```
class X
{
    public:
        X();
        virtual ~X();
        X* makeMethod(string Method);
    protected:

    private:
};

X* X::makeMethod(string Method){
    return new online();
}

class online: public X{
    public:
        online();
        virtual ~online();
        void makeMethod(string Method);
    protected:

    private: };
```

Como resolver esse erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare a classe antes de defini-la, pode até ser a primeira linha do arquivo:

```
class online {};
```

Assim você já pode usá-la no seu código e só depois defina como ela será implementada, como já o fez, o que pode ser depois dela já ter sido usada.

```
class online {};

class X {
    public:
        X();
        virtual ~X();
        X* makeMethod(string Method);
};

X* X::makeMethod(string Method) {
    return new online();
}

class online: public X {
    public:
        online();
        virtual ~online();
        void makeMethod(string Method);
};
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/OOP/DeclareClass.cpp).